# Trouble setting properties of a nested dictionary, Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I've recreated my error below, when trying to set a property in a nested dictionary then I get the error

```
"Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" on line 25, which is             registrationInfo[whichType!]![propKey] = propVal .
```

I think this comes from the unwrapping

```
registrationInfo[whichtype]!
```

which swift forces me to unwrap. Basically, how do I set nested dictionary properties which do not yet exist in the dict so therefore, yes, are nil, and need to NOT BE NIL because I need to set them?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var registrationInfo = [String:[String:Any]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func isTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        appendToRegistrationInfo(registrationInfo: &registrationInfo, whichType: "userInfo", propKey: "whichLanguage?", propVal: "swift")
    }
    
    func appendToRegistrationInfo(registrationInfo : inout[String : [String:Any]], whichType : String?, propKey : String, propVal : Any) {
        if whichType != nil {
            registrationInfo[whichType!]![propKey] = propVal
        }
        else {
            for (type, _) in registrationInfo {
                registrationInfo[type]![propKey] = propVal
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no need to swear and emote. Just ask the question. Your personal frustration is not a topic.

Comment: Hey @matt, it's good point and for goodness of the question, I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation doesn't look correct to me. You have a dictionary of type `[String: [String: Any]]` and I am assuming `whichType` is the key for the outer dictionary and `propKey` is the key for the inner dictionary.

The keys have to be non-nil so you can index into the outer and inner dictionaries. Then, you can just do:

```swift
if var innerDict = registrationInfo[whichType] {
   innerDict[propKey] = propVal
   registrationInfo[whichType] = innerDict
} else {
   registrationInfo[whichType] = [propKey: propVal]
}
```

Comment: Right, this is because the implementation is not correct. I have just merely fixed the force-unwrapping. I have now updated my answer to fix the implementation.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by the implementation is not correct. By design, the function should be called and set the properties it is passed. I don't know how else to implement that. And if the function doesn't set properties, but now doesn't error from force unwrapping, well I could have fixed that by deleting the function. But then I haven't set any properties....

Comment: Okay, it seems you edited it and it now sets properties too. Thanks!

Comment: The problem with the edited version is that it overwrites existing properties at registrationInfo[whichType] instead of appending a new property. Call the function twice to set two different properties with the same whichType parameter and see what I mean

Comment: Sorry, I have fixed that now.

Answer (score -1):

```
if let type = whichType { 

  if let info = registrationInfo[info], let prop = registrationInfo[info][propKey] 
  { 
     registrationInfo[info][propKey] = propVal
  }
}
```

You must be careful when you access directly to the `NSDictionary` value via key.

Try it within the block which starts `if whichType != nil {`

for `else` block

```
for (type, _) in registrationInfo { 
  if let type = registrationInfo[type], let prop = registrationInfo[type]![propKey] { 
     registrationInfo[info][propKey] = propVal
 }
}
```

It can be better for implementation but I believe it guards you from the `nil` errors.